# How to import components correctly in react app?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I found the following code. What does the @ stand for, is this a standard in react? What is a better way to import a component?

a)

```
import Box from '../../../components/Box '
```

b)

```
import Box from '@components/Box '
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Typescript (which the tag suggests you are) it's possible to setup "path mapping" in your tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@": ["./src"],
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@components": ["./src/components"]
    }
  }
}
```

reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping

So, it is difficult to update all paths in tsconfig.json so i would suggest to use 1st option

Answer (score 2):

`@components` is an alias for the components folder.

See how the example `a` you have to go down a bunch of folders so that you can reach the components one, relative to wherever that statement is being used? Well, the secondary option makes that a log simpler by considering everything being imported from the `components` folder as `@components`, so you no longer need to worry about figuring out where one folder is when comparing to where you are.

This does usually require more configuration with webpack if it's how you chose to do so. [Here is a blogpost I found explaining how and why](https://nimblewebdeveloper.com/blog/absolute-alias-imports-in-javascript-vscode)

Also, to answer the original question, they are both correct. `a` is just the more traditional and default way of doing it, and `b` is an alternative that may require some extra setup, but will keep your imports more organized and easier to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct, no real benefit other than both won't always work depending on what you need imported.

You would use **a)** for when you need to import component(s) that exist in the source code of your project.

For **b)**, you typically see this syntax when working with NPM packages that exist as dependencies in your project. Some of them are prefixed with an organization/library others are just the name of the library. For example: `import React from 'react';`

Comment: After realizing that the OP is using Typescript (not mentioned originally) I feel like an idiot, but I don't Typescript so not really. lol hopefully this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

For **Vite**:

vite.config.js:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import path from 'path'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@components': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/components'),
    }
  }
})
```